# MySql join after select - Slow query

Tags: mysql

I have 100,000 rows, and this query can sometimes take over 2 seconds. I'm trying to optimize it and had success with indexing the 'created' field with DESC. I'm trying to further optimise this query and am wondering if this query actually joins the 'tracks' on all 100,000 rows rather than just the 12 I actually need. Could this be causing a slower query?

Query:

```
SELECT `p`.`id` as performance_id, `p`.`performers`, `t`.`name` as track_name, `p`.`location`, `p`.`fms_id`
FROM (`performances` p)
JOIN `tracks` t ON `p`.`track` = `t`.`id`
WHERE (p.status = 1 OR (p.status != 2 && p.flagged < 3))
AND `p`.`prop` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '10', '11', '13') 
AND `p`.`track` IN ('17', '9', '5', '15', '2', '3', '8', '6', '12', '4', '1') 
AND `p`.`type` IN ('1', '0', '2') 
ORDER BY `p`.`created` desc
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  p   index   track,prop,flagged,status,type  created_desc    5   NULL    239 Using where
1   SIMPLE  t   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   database_name.p.track   1   Using where
```

Comment: You should also post the tables involved in the query and the other indexes you have.

Comment: Try moving all your IN statements up to the JOIN using JOIN.... AND.  Leave only the WHERE (p.status = 1 OR (p.status != 2 && p.flagged < 3)) as the WHERE clause.

Comment: Creating index on 'track' column of performances table would give the desired behavior (query won't join the 'tracks' on all 100,000 rows.)

Comment: I have indexes on all of the columns = fms_id, user_id, track, prop, flagged, status, featured, type, created. So that's good.

Comment: @bradleyg: Do you have one compound index or inddivudal indexes? Because in the case of the former, you should try changing the order of the columns in the compound index.

Comment: hmm, i did have a compound index, and i just removed which reduced my query by a huge amount. i guess this was the problem... incorrect ordering.

Comment: can you post the output of `SET profiling = 1; /* your query here */; SHOW PROFILE;`. I am sure we will find something interesting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use temp table for list of tracks and join that temp table with main query instead of using 'IN' clause. Generally, avoid IN clauses, as the number of items within the list goes up the query plan might change.

Creating index on 'track' column of performances table would give the desired behavior (query won't join the 'tracks' on all 100,000 rows.)

http://apps.ycombinator.com/item?id=2206406

http://dbaspot.com/sybase/240012-plan-change-clause-number-set-elements-print.html

Comment: Why should a temporary table be more efficient than an IN?

Comment: Or adding an appropriate index.

Comment: Is your statement with the increasing number with items in the IN clause a fact? (I.e. is it mentioned somewhere in the MySQL documentation?) And even if it would change, why should it make an access plan worse than creating a temporary table by itself?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this info available in documentation. But I've experienced similar behavior in sybase/ms sql server http://dbaspot.com/sybase/240012-plan-change-clause-number-set-elements-print.html